# Android View find ID

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm new for Android programing.
I have a View object. How can I find it id. I'm looking for the text id (not the integer) that was given in the XML file.
Thanks.

Comment: Which text id? Can you give an XML example or elaborate a bit?

Comment: The ID that was set in the Layout XML:     <TextView android:id="@+id/text" ...

Comment: But what is the R? I'm in the code and I have a View object. How can I find it grammatically?

Comment: R is a class that is automatically generated by the android tools. It contains ids for all (R)esources (views/layouts/styles and so on) in your project. You can find it in the `gen` folder of your project.

Comment: Wanting to do this in any sort of beginner context doesn't make much sense. You should probably give a broader explanation of what you are trying to achieve so you don't end up simply learning how to do something that's probably not good anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd typically use [Resources.getResourceEntryName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName%28int%29) for this, passing the numerical resource id as the parameter... i.e.

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

To use your example:  For a TextView decliared with:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text" ...>
```

The View doesn't have a text ID.  It just has an integer ID that the Android build process created, stashed in R.java, and created as the value "R.id.text".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it looks like you don't understand what your R file is or how android views work. You should probably go to the android tutorials [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial) and walk through at least the Hello World and Hello Views tutorials for a good introduction to android views and the meaning and generation of your R file.